# Chrome on Mac rendering font sizes inconsistently

Tags: css, google-chrome, cross-browser, font-size

I'm having an issue on two different macs running the same OS (10.7.5) and the same version of Chrome (24.0.1312.57). I am experiencing something very strange where it appears that the body font size is increased by 5%. I also noticed some lines of copy looking slightly larger and images/background images not filling their proper container. The site is coded using `body { font-size: 100%; }` and em's for everything else. I did a test from the computer that was giving me issues and changing the body font size to 95% made everything look consistant.

EDIT: Example with pics below. I was able to create a test scenario using this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kDJM7/1/)

You'll see in the second image, the box in em's exceeds the 400px underline. It's assumed that 25em = (400px / 16) when font size is 100%. On the third image, I reduced the font size to 95% and 400px now equals 25em.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give the url to test this issue ? It could simply be a "zoom" `cmd + "+"`

Comment: @soyuka cmd + "+/-" was my first reaction, but I leveled out both browsers using cmd + 0. Check out the post now, I have an example.

Comment: It's really weird, do you have some Accessibility options enabled in your system prefs ?

Comment: @soyuka so Chrome has a feature to change font size in Preferences > Advanced Settings > Web Content. The other computer was set to a custom font size. That was annoying haha.